# Prevent direct access to a php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I don't want to use .htaccess.

- **a.php b.php c.php compute.php**

**a.php b.php** and **c.php** uses it like this

$.get(**compute.php**?number=800)

I want **a.php** **b.php** and **c.php** to be
able to access **compute.php**

but I don't want to allow this to public.

http://localhost/**compute.php**?number=800

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. PHP files which are not under the webroot can't be accessed directly through a browser.

Comment: @HonkderHase: Those PHP files also cannot be accessed through [a jquery AJAX call](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), as was a requirement in the question.

Comment: What is `number=800` ?

Comment: Well, I'll give an answer: No, it is not possible. Anything that can be reached via a AJAX call is by definition public. That being said: There are many solutions to this problem. Which one is suitable for you depends on the actual problem you're trying to solve. You didn't tell us anything about this, so we cannot really help you. We can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between making an ajax call and navigate the target directly via web browser. So this is not possible. You can use a secret key and make it’s type post instead of get if you want your backend accept requests from only defined pages.

Answer (score 0):

if you import (require or include functions) the file, one way to do it is to create a pre-defined variable in `a.php b.php and c.php` which is not set on `compute.php` by default. Then you can check it in the `compute.php` file to see if it was imported by an authenticated "file"/"end".

But if you're required to use AJAX, you might want to implement authentication which is accessible to the public or access the file using the local IP address of the server. (which I think is too much complex and annoying solution)